# Call REST API from Azure Queue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-functions, background-process, azure-servicebus-queues

I know this question is wired, But I am not 100% sure if it is possible or not. Need expert advise.

I am using this architecture (see Fig 1), there is a MVC WebAPI which puts data in Azure Queue and then Queue will call Azure Function to perform small tasks but very large in number e.g Queue is sending 5k - 10k requests to Azure Function in 1 minute.

**Fig 1**
[image]

We want to remove Azure Function because it cost us a lot. We want to go for alternate of it.
For this, someone share an idea to remove Azure function with another MVC WebAPI. (see Fig 2)

**Fig 2**
[image]

Is above architecture is possible ? If yes then How and If no then can anyone please suggest anything?

Comment: azure function cost you a lot and you think webapp will be cheaper? how come? you can just function in the same app service plan and it won't cost you more

Comment: I’m curious to know why do you say that Azure Functions are costing you a lot of money. Would you mind elaborating that?

Comment: Monthly request is around 170M+ and Azure Function cost us 100$ monthly where as if we setup B1 App it will cost $9.49/month.

Comment: Question is can your B1 App will handle these many requests? Are you running your Function in consumption plans mode?

Comment: B1 can easily handle. What do you mean by "Function in consumption plans mode"

Comment: Are you specifying batchSize: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?

Comment: If your current MVC WebAPI is hosted on Azure in an App Service Plan, why not also host your Azure Function on the same plan and avoid incurring additional expense?

Comment: @SeanFeldman what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

When using Azure Functions with Storage Queue trigger, Azure Functions will scale out based on the load on the queue. By default, `batchSize` is set to 16. The setting can be configured via [`host.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?tabs=csharp#hostjson-settings)

> The number of queue messages that the Functions runtime retrieves simultaneously and processes in parallel. When the number being processed gets down to the newBatchThreshold, the runtime gets another batch and starts processing those messages. So the maximum number of concurrent messages being processed per function is batchSize plus newBatchThreshold. This limit applies separately to each queue-triggered function.

This setting alone might not be sufficient when the number of messages is substantial. In that case, you want to restrict the scale-out behaviour associated with the number of VMs used to execute the Function App. The setting is an App Setting `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT`. Setting it to 1 would prevent any scale-out to new VMs, but according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_max_dynamic_application_scale_out)

> This setting is a preview feature - and only reliable if set to a value <= 5

While your focus is on the cost of processing, take into consideration time as well. Unless it's OK to wait for the messages to get processed for a long time, you're likely to have other alternatives to Functions. But the trade-off between the cost and the time to process will always be there.